# How to calculate by road distance from one point to another in km from latitiude and longitude. Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, location

I actually need to calculate the distance from my current location to another location and i have the latitude and longitude of the two points. I want to get the road distance in km from my point(location) to another point. How can it be done.

Note: Not displacement.

Stuck with this for many days.

Comment: *"Stuck with this for many days."* - post the code you tried so far

Comment: **class LatLongDistanceCalcualtion {
  final Distance distance = Distance();

  // km = 423
  calcutalateDistance() {
    final num km = distance.as(LengthUnit.Kilometer,
        LatLng(9.591545, 76.522137), LatLng(9.594919, 76.510225));
    print('km $km');
    return km;
  }
} **
I have used latlong2: ^0.8.1 package to calculate, But the problem is it giving the displacement of two points we actually need road distance right?..

Comment: so you need to use `Google Distance Matrix API`

Comment: Ooh, Have you tried this..?, Let me try and will update you.

Comment: @pskink will this API gives the actual road distance in km?

Comment: either kms or miles

Comment: ooh ok. And that is paid right. To enable this API from console..?

Answer (score 0):

Use Google Distance Matrix API and enable Distance Matrix API from google cloud platform console.

```
void getDistanceAndDuration(LatLng origin, LatLng destination, ResponseCallback<DistanceDurationResponse?, String?> callback) async {
    try {
      var apiResponse = await _client.get("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=${origin.latitude},${origin.longitude}"
          "&destinations=${destination.latitude},${destination.longitude}&key=$mapApiKey&mode=DRIVING&",);

      DistanceDurationResponse response = DistanceDurationResponse.fromJson(apiResponse.data);
      var rows = response?.rows;

      if(rows != null && rows.isNotEmpty) {
        var elements = rows.first.elements;

        if(elements != null && elements.isNotEmpty) {
          var element = elements.first;
          var duration = element.duration;
          var distance = element.distance;

        }
      }

    } on DioError catch (e) {
      log(e.toString());
    } on FormatException catch (e) {
      log(e.toString());
    } catch (e) {
      log(e.toString());
    }
  }
```

_

```
class DistanceDurationResponse {

  String? status;
  List<Rows>? rows;
  List<String>? originAddresses;
  List<String>? destinationAddresses;

  DistanceDurationResponse({
    this.destinationAddresses,
    this.originAddresses,
    this.rows,
    this.status,
  });

  DistanceDurationResponse.fromJson(dynamic json) {
    destinationAddresses = json['destination_addresses'] != null ? json['destination_addresses'].cast<String>() : [];
    originAddresses = json['origin_addresses'] != null ? json['origin_addresses'].cast<String>() : [];
    if (json['rows'] != null) {
      rows = [];
      json['rows'].forEach((v) {
        rows?.add(Rows.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
    status = json['status'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final map = <String, dynamic>{};
    map['destination_addresses'] = destinationAddresses;
    map['origin_addresses'] = originAddresses;
    if (rows != null) {
      map['rows'] = rows?.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    map['status'] = status;
    return map;
  }
}

class Rows {
  List<DistanceDurationElement>? elements;

  Rows({this.elements,});

  Rows.fromJson(dynamic json) {
    if (json['elements'] != null) {
      elements = [];
      json['elements'].forEach((v) {
        elements?.add(DistanceDurationElement.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final map = <String, dynamic>{};
    if (elements != null) {
      map['elements'] = elements?.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return map;
  }
}

class DistanceDurationElement {

  String? status;
  EstimatedDistance? distance;
  EstimatedDuration? duration;

  DistanceDurationElement({
    this.distance,
    this.duration,
    this.status,
  });

  DistanceDurationElement.fromJson(dynamic json) {
    distance = json['distance'] != null ? EstimatedDistance.fromJson(json['distance']) : null;
    duration = json['duration'] != null ? EstimatedDuration.fromJson(json['duration']) : null;
    status = json['status'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final map = <String, dynamic>{};
    if (distance != null) {
      map['distance'] = distance?.toJson();
    }
    if (duration != null) {
      map['duration'] = duration?.toJson();
    }
    map['status'] = status;
    return map;
  }
}

class EstimatedDuration {

  int? value;
  String? text;

  EstimatedDuration({
    this.text,
    this.value,
  });

  EstimatedDuration.fromJson(dynamic json) {
    text = json['text'];
    value = json['value'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final map = <String, dynamic>{};
    map['text'] = text;
    map['value'] = value;
    return map;
  }
}

class EstimatedDistance {

  int? value;
  String? text;

  EstimatedDistance({
    this.text,
    this.value,
  });

  EstimatedDistance.fromJson(dynamic json) {
    text = json['text'];
    value = json['value'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final map = <String, dynamic>{};
    map['text'] = text;
    map['value'] = value;
    return map;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the effort, @Zakaria Hossain, Let me check this code and update you.

Comment: @abintictech did you try this solution and whats the status now?

Comment: yeah, i got the solution. It is actually a paid API of google(directions api). I have posted an answer of the code. Have a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

```
 class GetDistanceWithPolyLines {
// Object for PolylinePoints
 late PolylinePoints polylinePoints;

// List of coordinates to join
List<LatLng> polylineCoordinates = [];

  // Map storing polylines created by connecting two 
   points
 Map<PolylineId, Polyline> polylines = {};

 // Create the polylines for showing the route between two 
places

   createPolylines(
   double startLatitude,
   double startLongitude,
   double destinationLatitude,
   double destinationLongitude,
   ) async {
   // Initializing PolylinePoints
    polylinePoints = PolylinePoints();
   // Generating the list of coordinates to be used for
   // drawing the polylines
    PolylineResult result = await 
    polylinePoints.getRouteBetweenCoordinates(
  'You api key', // Google 
   Maps API Key
   PointLatLng(startLatitude, startLongitude),
   PointLatLng(destinationLatitude, destinationLongitude),
   travelMode: TravelMode.transit,
    );

    // Adding the coordinates to the list
    if (result.points.isNotEmpty) {
   result.points.forEach((PointLatLng point) {
    polylineCoordinates.add(LatLng(point.latitude, 
  point.longitude));
      });
   }


   return loopIt();
   }

   double _coordinateDistance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2) {
   var p = 0.017453292519943295;
    var c = cos;
     var a = 0.5 -
    c((lat2 - lat1) * p) / 2 +
    c(lat1 * p) * c(lat2 * p) * (1 - c((lon2 - lon1) * p)) 
  / 2;
  return 12742 * asin(sqrt(a));
 }

 double totalDistance = 0.0;

 // Calculating the total distance by adding the distance
 // between small segments

  var _placeDistance;
  loopIt() {
   for (int i = 0; i < polylineCoordinates.length - 1; 
   i++) {
  totalDistance += _coordinateDistance(
    polylineCoordinates[i].latitude,
    polylineCoordinates[i].longitude,
    polylineCoordinates[i + 1].latitude,
    polylineCoordinates[i + 1].longitude,
  );
   }
 return _placeDistance = totalDistance.toStringAsFixed(2);
}
}
```